# UserControl inside horizontal ListView cannot fill parent vertically

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, user-controls

I need to show `UserControl` for each of item in `ListView` horizontally. It can be done with `StackPanel`, but as I know `StackPanel` will wrap until content can be placed. But I need to fill parent(in this example `ListView`) vertically, like its `Grid` with multiple `ListBoxes`. By the way, my `UserControl` is this :

```
<UserControl x:Class="ResourceEditor.LanguagePanel"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:ResourceEditor.Resources"            
         xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:ResourceEditor.ViewModel">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DockPanel Grid.Row="1"  LastChildFill="True" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
        <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" DockPanel.Dock="Right" IsChecked="{Binding SortByThis}"></CheckBox>
        <UniformGrid Columns="2" Rows="0">
            <Button Content="{x:Static resources:Strings.Save}" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"></Button>
            <Button Content="{x:Static resources:Strings.Reset}" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Command="{Binding ResetCommand}"></Button>
        </UniformGrid>

    </DockPanel>


        <ListBox Grid.Row="0" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedWord}" ItemsSource="{Binding Words}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                    <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Mode=OneTime, Path=EnableEditingCommand}"
                            PassEventArgsToCommand="False" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="viewModel:WordNodeVM">
                <TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding DataContext.CanEdit, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBox>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

And this is how I use it:

```
  <ListView Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Languages}">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="1" Columns="{Binding Languages.Count}">

                </UniformGrid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{ x:Type viewModel:LanguagePanelViewModel}">
                <resourceEditor:LanguagePanel DataContext="{Binding}"></resourceEditor:LanguagePanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

I tried all possible solutions,changing container, using alignments, alignments for content, but was not be able to make my user control to fill vertical space. First I thought it is something wrong with `UserControl`, as it behaves like `StackPanel` maybe, but it is not neither.

Comment: WPF has a control called WrapPanel, Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I need vertically fill parent. But `WrapPanel` is even worse than `StackPanel` as wraps around minimal size of user control.

Answer (score 0):

I was not be able to find solution for current problem. But in terms of behavior that I wanted, I achieved that by this way:
I removed `ListView` from layout. Added empty `Grid`. And at background code, I added this

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        var model=new MainViewModel(loadGrid);
        DataContext = model;
        InitializeComponent();
        Closing += (s, e) => ViewModelLocator.Cleanup();

    }

    void loadGrid(IList<LanguagePanelViewModel> panels)
    {

        if (panels == null || !panels.Any())
            return;

        for (int i = 0; i < panels.Count; i++)
        {
            mainGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)});
            var panel = new LanguagePanel { DataContext = panels[i] };
            Grid.SetColumn(panel, i);
            mainGrid.Children.Add(panel);
        }
    }
```

I tried to not break MVVM rules, and this `loadGrid` method is called when my according list changes.As this does not answer the question, I will not accept it as answer in hope for robust answer.